# Concurrent std::call_once calls

Tags: c++, c++11

Could please someone explain me why both of the threads in this program (when compiled using the compilers shipped with Visual Studio 2012/2013) are blocked until both `std::call_once` calls are executed? Another Visual Studio bug (given that it behaves as expected when compiled with GCC)? Can someone please come up with a workaround? Imagine all the pain I've been through to narrow the problem down and please, be merciful.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

namespace
{
    std::once_flag did_nothing;

    void do_nothing()
    { }

    void sleep_shorter_and_do_nothing_once()
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
        std::cout << "1\n";
        std::call_once(did_nothing, do_nothing);
        std::cout << "2\n";
    }

    std::once_flag sleeped_longer;

    void sleep_longer()
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
    }

    void sleep_longer_once()
    {
        std::cout << "3\n";
        std::call_once(sleeped_longer, sleep_longer);
        std::cout << "4\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(sleep_shorter_and_do_nothing_once);
    std::thread t2(sleep_longer_once);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

To elaborate, it behaves as expected when compiled using GCC:

- prints "3",
- waits 3 seconds,
- prints "1",
- immediately prints "2",
- waits another 6-7 seconds,
- and prints "4".

When compiled using the compilers shipped with Visual Studio 2012/2013, it behaves like this:

- prints "3",
- waits 3 seconds,
- prints "1",
- *waits another 6-7 seconds*,
- *and only then immediately prints "2" and "4"*.

Clearly, it's a misbehavior. Or isn't it?

**UPDATE:** I cannot submit this as a Visual Studio bug, because my work account is for some reason "not authorized to submit feedback for this connection", whatever this means. I've got a reply from the Microsoft STL maintainer saying he'll hopefully investigate the issue at some time in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got a reply from the STL maintainer at Microsoft saying the bug's fixed in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: if it is a public reply link into your answer

Comment: @UmNyobe I'm sorry, it was an email. It was a long time ago, anyway. And I clearly shouldn't fix grammar/formatting in my older questions, as it for some reason spurred a great deal of new comments!

Comment: Mentioned in VS2015 release notes, under DevDiv#1092852 : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/07/14/stl-fixes-in-vs-2015-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

It prefers to be a misbehavior. 
"The completion of an effective call to call_once on a once_flag object synchronizes with all subsequent calls to call_once on **the same once_flag** object." (N3242, 30.4.4.2-clause-3).